# Does Google Code have anything comparable to GitHub pull requests?

Tags: git, svn, github, google-code

Does Google Code (svn or git) has any thing comparable to GitHub pull request so that other can easily  contribute to a project?

Comment: That's (one thing of) what the issue tracker is used for, so for now there is no equivalent. For your own project you can add your own  issue label for that although most projects I know don't have something like that.

Comment: @mbx so one should create a patch and then submit patch files? can I then merge the patch online or see diff online?

Comment: depends on how your project is distributed. One could rebuild that using the google code API, but merging "offline" is the usual way to go.

Comment: @mbx what exactly do you mean by "depends on how your project is distributed" and "one could rebuild that using the google code API"?

Comment: You can script something around the [Issue Tracker API](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/IssueTrackerAPI).

Comment: If you add a template for Pull-Requests, it may look like [this](http://code.google.com/p/btuswphalma/issues/entry?template=Pull%20Request). Just give your remote and a commit in the commits section in the right format...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

<s>Not yet, though this is [an accepted issue](https://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=4753&q=pull%20request&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary) (star it!).</s>

[Google Code was discontinued on March 12, 2015!](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html)